# Automated login on ASP.NET website with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, webforms

I have to login with a username / password with a c# program with asp.net form.

I have already do that with HttpUtility on PHP website but how to do that with ASP.NET website ?

In ASP.NET, I must handle postback and so on... Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

UPDATE :

I have to privilegied access to this website. I have to login like any other visitor. I don't know if it clarify enough the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I will use the watin library (http://watin.sourceforge.net/) wich is exactly what I needed.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Daniel is right the ASP.NET MembershipProvider is what your looking for. Here is a nice **walkthorough** the [**ASP.NET Membership Provider**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c(VS.80).aspx).

It explains in details what to do to let people register/sign on/off.

Comment: He wants to programmatically interact with an ASP.Net website, posting informationand reading the response.  Knowing Membership won't help.

Comment: Ok, your guessing skills seem to be much more advanced than mine ;) I seriously though he is getting into ASP.NET development coming from a php background. Even after reading it again ;)

Comment: I'm taking my guessing from the C# Program, and HttpUtility.... Plus I've done something like this before...

Comment: +1 I agree, the question was not detailed enough to draw too many conclusions about requirements

Comment: I have to privilegied access to this website. I have to login like any other visitor. I don't know if it clarify enough the question

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Membership Providers provided by ASP.NET